# Absolute simplest server-side Javascript mechanism?

Tags: javascript, serverside-javascript

I've got a simple Javascript application with a JSON API. Currently it runs in the client, but I'd like to move it from the client to the server. I am accustomed to learning new platforms, but in this case, my time is very limited - so I need to find the absolute simplest way possible.

This should be an easy task, but all I'm finding are solutions that are *way* overcomplicated:

- The application is currently hosted on an extremely basic server. Node.js is not available, and I do not have install privileges. I'll eventually move it to a different server, but I really don't know what will be available there.
- Many solutions require installing and running a standalone server. Really? Just to evaluate Javascript server-side and spit out some data?
- I can run Python and PHP, and I see that it's possible to call Javascript from inside a Python or PHP script. However, the specific Python solution that I've found also require installing some Python support via pip or easy-install, so probably not an option. Also, this just feels overcomplicated, and I'm concerned about setting myself up for errors such as data conversion or permissions, etc.

Any help?

Comment: In order to execute JavaScript on the server you will need a JavaScript compiler on the server. There isn't any way around that.

Comment: Good question imho. Wouldn't it be cool to have an apache server execute JS on the server like it does with CGI.

Comment: @Shanimal — You mean spawn an external process (i.e. node) for every single request? It can. It's just that nobody does that because its horribly inefficient and nicer options (like Express) exist. (And you would still need a JavaScript compiler, like Node, installed in order to execute the JS CGI program).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Quentin is correct. There is no way to run javascript on a server without a javascript interpreter on the server.

Node.js is not only the most robust and widely used one, it's also the *simplest*. It is certainly possible to write your own javascript interpreter in PHP or Python, but that would be *much* more complicated than using Node.js.

Try really hard to find a server solution that allows you to use Node. In the end, it's going to save you (and any other stakeholders interested in the project) a lot of time and money.